# c# marshalling try to return struct from cpp dll to c# application which gets allocated be the dll it self

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling

I have the following problem:

I try to call this c++ function from my c# appllication:

```
int get_struct_from_dll (some_struct** return_struct);

int get_struct_form_dll (some_struct** return_struct) {
     some_struct st;
     st.some_void_pointer = nullptr;
     st.some_string = "some_string";

     some_struct* st_ptr = &st;
     *return_stuct = return_struct;

return 1;
}
```

`return_struct` is a double pointer because `get_struct_from_dll` has to allocate the mermory it self.
It also only contains one element threrefore no size info is needed.

`some_struct` looks like this:

```
typedef struct {
     void        *some_void_pointer;      
     const char  *some_string;                                                                       
} some_struct;
```

Now on the c# side:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct some_struct
{
        public IntPtr instance;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public string host;
}
```

```
        [DllImport(_dllPath)]
     
        public static extern ReturnTypes get_struct_form_dll (IntPtr server);

        IntPr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(IntPtr)));

        get_struct_form_dll(ptr);

        IntPtr ptrptr = Marshal.ReadintPtr(ptr);

        some_struct st= (some_struct) Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptrptr, typeof(some_struct));
```

The Problem now is that when i print `st` it just returns garbadge, but no Errors are getting Thrown.

Please Help !

What i also tried:
I did change my c# code to the following:

```
    [DllImport(_dllPath)]
     
        public static extern ReturnTypes get_struct_form_dll (out IntPtr server);

        IntPr ptr;

        get_struct_form_dll(out ptr);

        some_struct st = (some_struct) Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(some_struct));
```

This resulted in exactly the same result as previously.

Comment: `out` might fix this, like `public static extern ReturnTypes get_struct_form_dll (out IntPtr server);`

Comment: `out` didnt fix it. I get exactly the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution to my problem.

The solution is that on the c++ side the memory is automaticly freed after the return.
This results in the c# reading unallocated memory which obvisly doesnt work.

Therefore the solution is to change the c++ side to the following:

```
int get_struct_form_dll (some_struct** return_struct) {

  some_struct* st = (some_struct*) malloc(sizeof(some_struct));
  
  *return_struct = st;

  return 1;
}
```

This prevents the data from being delted after the call.

Be carefully because at the moment the malloc call is never freed.
Which results in a memory leak.